# Is there a way to handle remote notification in iOS today extension directly?

Tags: ios, firebase, widget, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a today extension, and I'm looking for a way to update it by receiving realtime data from remote push notification. Currently my app's using FCM, and I'm trying to receive foreground silent push from FCM and update today extension accordingly. I've tried and searched for a while, didn't find a way, and I'm about to conclude it is impossible. Or is it feasible?

Comment: Yes you can always update the today extension data its possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've write an update flag in shared keychain when I get a specific remote push notification item in UNNotificationServiceExtension and updated widget in repeated timer callback by checking it. Couldn't find better solution.